# How to create Logins on VB.net.

Tags: vb.net

I need serious help with my software.
Im making a system for an election.
I need to make a login which reads and identifies text from the text file and if it is the correct user name and password in the textboxes then it opens another form. I have to make a textfile which will allow various users to login. Im currently using vb 2010.
Thanks

Comment: Could you share your efforts???

Comment: use streamwriter to store and streamreader to retrieve your login password ..

Answer (score 1):

You are in luck! I have just made my own system :)

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\ProgramData\Hax Client\User Data\Temp Users\" + txtUsername.Text + ".txt")) Then
    ElseIf (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\ProgramData\Hax Client\User Data\" + txtUsername.Text + ".txt")) Then
        Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\ProgramData\Hax Client\User Data\" + txtUsername.Text + ".txt")
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                        Dim unpw() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split("|")
                        'example is username|password
                        'our array is now unpw(0) = username
                        '                 unpw(1) = password
                        If txtUsername.Text = unpw(0) And txtPassword.Text = unpw(1) Then
                            'sucess
                            'Loads new form once correct details have been entered
                            If (unpw(0) = "guest" And unpw(1) = "guest") Then
                                Dim GuestWindow As New GuestWindow
                                GuestWindow.Show()
                                Me.Close()
                            Else
                                Dim MainWindow As New MainWindow
                                MainWindow.Show()
                                Me.Close()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End While
        End Using
    Else
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\ProgramData\Hax Client\User Data\Temp Users\" + txtUsername.Text + ".txt", "Failed Login! Used username: " + txtUsername.Text, False)
    End If
End Sub
```

Now the way I made mine work was in "C:\ProgramData\Hax Client\Users\.txt"

Text file:

```
<username>|<password>
```

Just name the textfile as the username for simplicity. You could try encoding them? But i'm not sure how.

Anyways if you need anymore help just reply :) Also within the Users folder I made \Temp Users this is where failed logins go, and then are cleared once logged in. Its to stop the coding from crashing.

Skype: nfell2009

Comment: The code ignores the "|": Dim unpw() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split("|") - Splitting the code into 2 parts, the username and password. I have bothered to encrypt them. If you want look on MSDN or Google it.